# Can I install the all the software included with Ubuntu Studio on Kubuntu without losing the KDE environment?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments, ubuntu-studio

I am planning on installing Ubuntu on my new laptop, but I prefer the KDE Plasma 5 DE and I am likely going to use a lot of creation software like that which is included in Ubuntu Studio. I don't know if this is the right place to ask this but is there a way to install all the software from Ubuntu Studio in Kubuntu without switching my desktop environment? I just want the software.
Thanks in advance and I apologize if this isn't a good place to ask this!

Comment: Which applications do you want installed?   My experience with that combination was not that good.  Can be unstable.

Comment: I want to install at least Blender, OpenShot, FFMPEG, DVDStyler, GIMP, Ardour, and Audacity. Would it be easier to just install them individually?

Comment: GIMP, Ardour and Audacity will work just fine.  FFMPEG is part of Kubuntu-restricted-extras.  Don't know about Blender, OpenShot or DVDStyler. Yes, install individually.  Then check for any comaptibility issues after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291746/use-gnome-shell-in-ubuntu-studio-or-ubuntu-studio-functionality-in-vanilla-ubun) and on the Ubuntu Studio wiki (linked below), but since we want KDE rather than Gnome or XFCE (Ubuntu Studio's default DE) we'll do things a little differently. As of writing this, I'm running  Kubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

1. First Install [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/), if it's not already on your system.
2. Open a terminal to update Kubuntu, install Ubuntu Studio packages and low latency kernel:
   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-audio-plugins ubuntustudio-graphics ubuntustudio-video linux-lowlatency`

   - You may also want to add `ubuntustudio-menus`
3. Follow the `configuration modifications` section [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu%20Studio%20Upgrade%20from%20Ubuntu) to finish setting up Ubuntu Studio. note: most of the steps listed here are unnessecary for newer versions of ubuntu, however users should still be added to audio/video groups with  `sudo adduser <username> video` and  `sudo adduser <username> audio`

---

*If you already have Ubuntu Studio installed,* you can install KDE Plasma over Ubuntu Studio, although I do not recommend this as I've run into  problems like conflicting dependencies or things vanishing after upgrades. It just seems Unnecessary to have multiple desktop environments installed.